# Avoid using global, creating variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

I'm using Ecmascript 3 on Rhino JavaScript engine. The process starts with connecting a remote server and download scripts from there.

I need to import my JavaScript libraries that would work on Linux agent like this:

```
/*
#import lib/*.js
*/

init(this);
function init(){
   var foo = lib.foo;
   var constants = lib.constant;
   ////some logic here

}
```

So, my script agent tries to download script files from server, and it needs to import all of the libraries that I wrote up.

I already tried to use lazy loading but it's too hard to implement all files right now and idea, how could I simplify this process?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Then don't import them all?

Comment: i dont need to import all of the codes which are these libraries include. i only need part of them for example; not all jquery library but just 1 or 2 methods, i mean not eager.